# Get an associative array from input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to have an associative array from a form with multiple text input with jQuery (or directly in JS). From that :

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name[13]" value="test 1" />
<input type="text" name="name[14]" value="test 2" />
<input type="text" name="new_name[]" value="test 3" />
</form>
```

I would like to get that :

```
name : Array {
    13 => "test 1",
    14 => "test 2"
}
new_name : Array {
    1 => "test 3"
}
```

I try with the serialize function of jQuery and it works only for array like the new_name one.

Thanks for your help !
Kevin

Comment: Hi, I noticed the "Kevin" at the end, please note that signatures are not very allowed in StackOverflow (both in comments and posts).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
var output = [];

$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {

  var s = $(this).attr('name').match(/(.*)[(.*)]/);

  var found = false;
  for(x in output) {
    if(x == s[0]) {
      output[x].push({s[1]: $(this).val()});
      found = true;
    }
  }

  if(!found) {
    output[s[0]] = [{s[1]: $(this).val()}];
  }

});
```

Comment: I've got a page with a lot of form (an administration page with a lot of "object" that I want to modify directly in ajax. I can't pass in review each input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, (I would avoid using jQuery in this particular case)

```
window.onload=function(){//$(document).ready(...) if you already using jQuery
    var str,str2,arr1=[],arr2=[],inputs=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0,len=inputs.length;i<len;i++){
        str=inputs[i].name;
        if(inputs[i].type=='text'&&str.charAt(str.length-1)=="]"){
            if(str.substr(0,5)=="name["){
                str2=parseInt(str.split("name[")[1].split("]")[0]);
                if(str2!=NaN){
                    arr1[str2]=inputs[i].value;
                    continue;//we move to the next i
                }//else
            }
            if(str.substr(0,9)=="new_name["){
                str2=parseInt(str.split("new_name[")[1].split("]")[0]);
                if(str2!=NaN){
                    arr2[str2]=inputs[i].value;
                }//else
            }
        }
    }
    alert(arr1[13]);//test 1
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PjFrt/6/)

**Note:** When the index is not valid, it won't add it to the arrays, you can easily modify the `//else` to do something else

Comment: Your function doesn't keep in memory indexs I've set in the html code (13 and 14). I need these index...

Comment: @Kevin I have updated my answer. by the way `new_name[]` have an empty index, what would you like to happen?

Comment: With your edit, I've now the same problem that with the solution of techfoobar (I've got a page with a lot of form (an administration page with a lot of "object" that I want to modify directly in ajax. I can't pass in review each input).

Answer (score -2):

What output do you get (in Firebug or Chrome console) if you add the code below and submit the form:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  console.log($(this).serializeArray());
  return false;
});
```

EDIT: this was for the purpose of trying to find out what the OP's issue was in more detail..

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here is what I get :

    Array
    (
    
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => ean[3967]
                [value] => 3700275175119
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => ean[5155]
                [value] => 1234
            )
    
        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => ean[]
                [value] => 
            )
    
    )

(Sorry for the format. I don't know how to post format code when commenting a message).